# Logstash difference between add_field and replace

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

What is the difference between `add_field` and `replace`, when configuring Logstash?

Semantically, they might expected to do different things, but the [current manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) does not have anything to say about how the two functions differ depending on the pre-existance of the relevant fields.

Example 1:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" }
  }
}
```

The manual does not say what the expected behavour is if the field already exists. Is the behaviour the same as `replace`?

Example 2:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    replace => { "message" => "%{source_host}: My new message" }
  }
}
```

Once again the manual does not say what the expected behaviour is if the field does not already exist. Is it the same as `add_field`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Briefly, in my scenario it looked like add_field was appending values. I asked the question as I was hoping for a more official / documented answer regarding the intended behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Semantically, they might seem equivalent but they are different as `add_field` might not always kick in.

`replace` is part of the `mutate` filter and if you're [looking at the source code of that plugin](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb#L237-L241), you'll see that replace will **always** set a field even if it doesn't exist:

```
  def replace(event)
    @replace.each do |field, newvalue|
      event.set(field, event.sprintf(newvalue))
    end
  end
```

`add_field`, however, is a generic configuration of any input and filter plugins and you'll often see in the documentation of some specific filter plugins something like this (e.g. for the [`grok`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_field) filter):

> If this filter is successful, add any arbitrary fields to this event. [...]

This configuration is inherited from [`LogStash::Filters::Base`](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/cb8d80a46f7a845037f1095b0c973c593c11ba0a/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb#L68-L93), which is the superclass of all filter plugins. This means that in certain filter plugins, in order for `add_field` to actually add the field, the filter **must be successful**, otherwise no fields is added.

So in your case, `mutate/replace` will always set a field even if it doesn't exist, and `mutate/add_field` will add the specified fields after running all the operations of the mutate filter.

So if you have a mutate filter that does some specific operation like `gsub` and fails for some reason, no fields will be added as a result.